# Can I use a variable to define a Range in the Range("X:X") format

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I currently have a formula which checks for:

```
If Intersect(Target, Range("J:L")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
```

I need L to be a variable, the 2nd part of the range is essentially J+ an Offset. I've used L here and it works however I need it to be dynamic which is why I'd like to replace L with a variable.

I did search for answers but the only ones I could find used cell references in the range format rather than column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want do define a range that is a variable **offset** from column **J** then consider:

```
Sub dural()
    '
    '   N will be the number of extra columns
    '   so if N=0 we want Range("J:J")
    '   and if N=1 we want Range("J:K")
    '   etc.
    '

    Dim N As Long
    N = 3
    Set r = Range("J:" & Chr(N + 74))
    MsgBox r.Address
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

If you need to get to a column beyond column **Z**, then use this instead:

```
Sub dural2_TheSequel()
    '
    '   N will be the number of extra columns
    '   so if N=0 we want Range("J:J")
    '   and if N=1 we want Range("J:K")
    '   etc.
    '

    Dim N As Long
    N = 3
    Ch = Replace(Cells(1, N + 10).Address(0, 0), "1", "")
    Set r = Range("J:" & Ch)
    MsgBox r.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you I actually came up with a solution very similar to this before I checked back in. I'll tick the one that was closest to what I wanted to achieve. I was using a function to convert the column number to a column letter but I like your solution!

Comment: Yeh I figured that would be the case when I looked up the char codes in VBA. In the end I switched it around a bit and used a function to convert column numbers into there respective character notations and then added that to the second half of the formula.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of this, you're using this in a VBA Function, not a cell formula. In that case, you can build a string that is the address of the range. The code above becomes:

```
Dim sRangeAddress as String
'Set the Address here
sRangeAddress = "J:L"
If Intersect(Target, Range(sRangeAddress)) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
```

Edited to add:
To calculate the end letter of the range, the you can create a formula to  do it:

```
Dim sRangeAddress as String
Dim iAdditionalColumns as int
dim iManyAdditonalColumns as Int
iAdditionalColumns = 1
sRangeAddress = "J:"
'Set the Address here
'Put conditional for going past Column Z
If (iAdditionalColumns + 74) > 90 Then
    iManyAdditonalColumns  = (iAdditionalColumns - 16) / 26
    iAdditionalColumns  = (iAdditionalColumns - 16) Mod 26
    sRangeAddress = sRangeAddress  + Chr(64 + iManyAdditonalColumns) 
End If  
sRangeAddress = sRangeAddress  + Chr(64 + iAdditionalColumns) 

If Intersect(Target, Range(sRangeAddress)) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
```

If you need the count of the columns to be dynamic, you will have to write code to determine the number of columns...

Comment: Sorry this is VBA yes, I've got what you mentioned already working but I need the 2nd column reference (L) to be a variable. The default setting for this range is ("J:J") I calculate an offset which is determined by how many additional columns are added so in the above example 2 additional columns have been added so the range is now ("J:L"). I'd like to use this offset to determine the 2nd column reference dynamically